# Can't see the table on Hive

Tags: database, hadoop, hive

I am new and i was following a tutorial so i might be giving some unnecessary info. I used beeline to connect to hive. Then i created a table named "adv_sales_gt_20" using the following command

```
create table test1.adv_sales_gt_20 as select * from test1.advertising where sales > 20.0;
```

When i use "show tables;" it shows the tables except the one i just created. When i try to create it again, it says table already exists, so it is actually there.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c1CFx.png)

I tried confirming using the explorer GUI and i can see that the table is there.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoIM9.png)

I can run commands such as "select" etc. on the table.
But as i said, i can't see it on the terminal when i run show tables;

Comment: Table is owned by TEST1. When you're running *show tables*, are you connected as TEST1?

Comment: Thank you, as you suggested i had to use *use test1;* before running the *show tables;*  which i didn't know before. I've been trying to search on /warehouse instead of /warehouse/test1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should run `show tables` under owner of the table

```
use test1
```

`show tables` works as expected